# How to use Laplacian of Gaussian for elliptical blobs?

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, scikit-image, laplacianofgaussian

Currently, the Scikit image package implements Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG) to find spherical blobs. The package is [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_blob.html). How can one convert these Laplacian of Gaussian to an elliptical Gaussian kernel? This is required to get the non-spherical blobs in an image.

Comment: The min_sigma, max_sigma of LoG can take a sequence of scalars, so you can specify the desired values for each axis of your ellipse. Check the [LoG documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.blob_log).

Comment: This doesn't check for all possible combination of sigma. For example if I give, min_sigma = [3,4] , max_sigma = [10,11] and num_sigma = 7. The LoG implemented in scikit-image only considers sigma (x,y) values  such as (3,4), (4,5), (5,6) and so on. However, I also want sigma values of (3,5), (3,6), (5,3), etc.